# WSO2 Integration Studio Payload factory Bad Syntax error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am Using Wso2 Integration studio to expose an endpoint while sending the request body in the payload factory mediator. I have around 35 properties in the request body. As I enter above 29 properties the endpoint starts giving me a response of 400 response.(The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad request).

[image: Error Response]

My rest API is given below.

[image: Created Rest API]

```
{"Property1":true, "Property2":false, "Property3":true, "Property4":true, "Property5":true, "Property6":true, "Property7":false, "Property8":true, "Property9":false, "Property10":true, "Property11":true, "Property12":true, "Property13":true, "Property14":1209, "Property15":46, "Property16":1209, "Property17":46, "Property18":12, "Property19":6, "Property20":false, "Property21":false, "Property22":"somestring", "Property23":null, "Property24":null, "Property25":true, "Property26":false, "Property27":false, "Property28":$1, "Property29":$2, "Property30":$3}
```

It was working and giving a 200 OK response for the below request,

```
{"Property1":true, "Property2":false, "Property3":true, "Property4":true, "Property5":true, "Property6":true, "Property7":false, "Property8":true, "Property9":false, "Property10":true, "Property11":true, "Property12":true, "Property13":true, "Property14":1209, "Property15":46, "Property16":1209, "Property17":46, "Property18":12, "Property19":6, "Property20":false, "Property21":false, "Property22":"somestring", "Property23":null, "Property24":null, "Property25":true, "Property26":false, "Property27":false, "Property28":$1, "Property29":$2}
```

**Update
This happens in the normal flow as well. That means the problems occurs when I just try to use the below configuration as well.

[image]
Please help me resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the wso2carbon.log or are getting this error from your backend. ? Also, can you create a minimal reproducible sample and add the code so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ycr I don't have any errors in the carbon.log. This happens when i test the endpoint on the postman.